# When focus other fields change automatically keyboard layout on safari

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

When I change `keyboard layout` to other languages in safari browser, then I focused other fields, the keyboard layout has been changed to default system keyboard language! my phone is: iPhone 6g Version: 12.4.

**CODE:**

```css
  form input {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" />
    </form>

</body>
```

[image]